# Comparing different data-types in PostgreSQL.

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

it's been a while since I have made one of my "Converting MySQL to PostgreSQL" posts.

So, today's problem is as follows:

The original MySQL queries involve where clauses which look a bit like the following:

```
 WHERE id LIKE '%6%' 
 OR createdtime LIKE '%6%' 
 OR modifiedtime LIKE '%6%' 
 OR start_date LIKE '%6%' 
 OR end_date LIKE '%6%' 
 OR sc_related_to LIKE '%6%' 
 OR tracking_unit LIKE '%6%'
 OR message LIKE '%6%'
```

This query is part of a system wide search. In this case, the system is searching for `6`, had I asked it to search for something else, like say the word `user`, instead of `%6%`, we'd have `%user%`.

Now, the problem is that, the above data-types are not always strings. Integer fields like `id` and date/time fields like `createdtime` are being compared to strings. In MySQL, this seems to be okay, but grumpy PostgreSQL gets grumpy when it sees this query.

I know that for some fields, I can use the `to_char` function, so, for example, part of the clause in PostgreSQL might look like this:

```
 to_char(id, '999') LIKE '%6%'
```

Unfortunately, I can't just go throught the queries and add the `to_char` to each applicable field because of the PHP backend. This is what the PHP code for generating the `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
 $where .= $tablename.".".$columnname." LIKE '". formatForSqlLike($search_val) ."'";
```

Note: It's part of a loop, so the above line generates all of the individual comparisons.

So, even if I can get around the type comparison with `to_char`, I can't implement it because `to_char` might need a specific 2nd parameter for a different data-type and even if I could use the same parameter for all data-types, some of the data-types would be strings, and passing a string to `to_char` throws an error.

So, I need a way to either get PHP to determine the column type and use the right `to_char`(or don't use it at all) accordingly or I need to get PostgreSQL to compare different data-types.

Thanks for all of your help, have a good day!

Comment: What sense does it make to use LIKE against a `date` column?

Comment: I don't know...I didn't write the code. :( I guess, it's there so that if a user searched a date it could get some results, but I don't know how well `LIKE` works with `dates`.

Comment: `PostgreSQL gets grumpy when it sees this query`... which speaks well of PosgresSQL.

Comment: Oh Postgres is fine, it just doesn't put up with as much silliness as mySQL..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just cast everything to a string, such as:

```
$where .= $tablename.".".$columnname."::text LIKE '". formatForSqlLike($search_val) ."'";
```

If you don't want to change the PHP code, another idea is to create a `VIEW` that does the cast, such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TableName AS
   SELECT
     createdtime::text,
     modifiedtime::text,
     start_date::text,
     end_date::text,
     sc_related_to::text,
     tracking_unit::text,
     message::text
   FROM RealTable;
```

Then your PHP code would just use this view instead of the table, and see everything as text.

However, I believe your technique here is really not going to scale well.  Every search will probably be doing a sequential scan of the entire table, since `LIKE` clauses cannot be indexed.

Your best bet is to re-design this using a [`FULLTEXT` search index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html), which will be way more versatile as well as lightning fast.

Comment: Oh my, thanks for that. It was silly of me not to try casting it like that. The `FULLTEXT search` seems really interesting, but unfortunately, implementing it in this system would probably be very time consuming and painful. I will, however, keep that in mind when and if I ever have to design a search from scratch.

Comment: Yup!  But at least now you can bring it up to the powers that be, and when it all comes crashing down say you told them so.

Comment: If you use the standards-compliant CAST(colname AS text) then you'll have less porting work to do, too.